# Having issues with Calendar Printing based on the input from the user

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PrintCalendarV1 {
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    inputMonthMethod();     
    if(MonthOfTheYear>0&&MonthOfTheYear<13){
        inputYearMethod();
        if(Year>0){
            leapYearCheck();
            inputDayMethod();
            printCalendar();    
        }
        else System.out.println("Invalid Entry for Year");
    }
    else System.out.println("Invalid Entry for Month.");
    
}

// Declarations
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static int DayOfTheWeek;
static int MonthOfTheYear;
static int Year;
static int NumberOfDays;

//Methods to take inputs
public static void inputMonthMethod(){
    System.out.println("Enter Month: 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, 3 for Mar ... 12 for Dec");
    MonthOfTheYear = input.nextInt();
}
public static void inputYearMethod(){
    System.out.println("Enter Year: ");
    Year = input.nextInt();
}
public static void inputDayMethod(){
    System.out.println("Enter Starting Day of the Month: 1 for Sun, 2 for Mon, ... 7 for Sat");
    DayOfTheWeek = input.nextInt();
}
public static void leapYearCheck() {
    if(Year%4!=0||Year%100!=0||Year%400!=0){
        if(MonthOfTheYear==1||MonthOfTheYear==3||MonthOfTheYear==5||MonthOfTheYear==7||MonthOfTheYear==8||MonthOfTheYear==10||MonthOfTheYear==12)
        {NumberOfDays = 31;}
        else if(MonthOfTheYear==4||MonthOfTheYear==6||MonthOfTheYear==9||MonthOfTheYear==11)
        {NumberOfDays = 30;}
        else
        {NumberOfDays=28;}
    }
    else{
        if(MonthOfTheYear==1||MonthOfTheYear==3||MonthOfTheYear==5||MonthOfTheYear==7||MonthOfTheYear==8||MonthOfTheYear==10||MonthOfTheYear==12)
        {NumberOfDays = 31;}
        else if(MonthOfTheYear==4||MonthOfTheYear==6||MonthOfTheYear==9||MonthOfTheYear==11)
        {NumberOfDays = 30;}
        else
        {NumberOfDays=29;}

    }   
}
public static void printCalendar() {
    System.out.println("\n \t \t \t"+MonthOfTheYear+"--"+Year+"\t \t");
    System.out.println("\n SUN \t MON \t TUE \t WED \t THU \t FRI \t SAT"); 
    leapYearCheck();//It is supposed to run the leapYearMethod to check if the Year is Leap Year to set No. of Days in Feb = 29. 
    //But this is not happening;
    for(int i=1; i<=DayOfTheWeek;i++){
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if(DayOfTheWeek==1){//yes
        for(int x=1; x<DayOfTheWeek;x++){
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfDays; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i+"\t");
            if(DayOfTheWeek%7>0) System.out.println();
    }
    else if(DayOfTheWeek==2){
        for(int x=1; x<DayOfTheWeek;x++){
            System.out.print("");
        }
        
        for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfDays; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i+"\t");
            if(DayOfTheWeek%7>0) System.out.println();
        }
    }
    else if(DayOfTheWeek==3){
        for(int x=1; x<DayOfTheWeek;x++){
            System.out.print(" \t");
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfDays; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i+"\t");
            if(DayOfTheWeek%7>0) System.out.println();
        }
    }
    else if(DayOfTheWeek==4){
        for(int x=1; x<DayOfTheWeek;x++){
            System.out.print(" \t");
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfDays; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i+"\t");
            if(DayOfTheWeek%7>0) System.out.println();
        }
    }
    else if(DayOfTheWeek==5){
        for(int x=1; x<DayOfTheWeek;x++){
            System.out.print(" \t");
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfDays; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i+"\t");
            if(DayOfTheWeek%7>0) System.out.println();
        }
    }
    else if(DayOfTheWeek==6){
        for(int x=1; x<DayOfTheWeek;x++){
            System.out.print(" \t");
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfDays; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i+"\t");
            if(DayOfTheWeek%7>0) System.out.println();
        }
    }`enter code here`
    else if(DayOfTheWeek==7){
        for(int x=1; x<DayOfTheWeek;x++){
            System.out.print(" \t");
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfDays; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i+"\t");
            if(DayOfTheWeek%7>0) System.out.println();
        }
    }
    else System.out.println("Invalid Entry for DayOfTheWeek.");
}
}
```

**This is how I wanted to print the calendar**

```
S  M Tu  W Th  F  S
                   1 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31
```

**This is what I am getting**

```
 SUN     MON     TUE     WED     THU     FRI     SAT
                                 1      
 2
 3
 4      
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 19
 20
 21
 22
 23
 24
 25
 26
 27
 28
 29
 30
 31
```

1. `checkLeapYear()` is not working.
2. Printing format

Comment: This would be easier to read if you followed the java naming conventions. Classes begin with an upper case letter: variables and methods begin with a lower case letter.

Comment: Is this code you downloaded from somewhere  that you are trying to use for a class project? It's printing the weeks that way in an obvious println statement.

Comment: You can use the java [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) to do all the calculations for you. All you need to do is format the output. Are you not allowed to use the date-time API?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something similar to the [cal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cal_(Unix)) command in UNIX.
The code you posted in your question does exactly what it is supposed to. You have written the code in such a way that it will not produce the output that you want. For example you call method [println()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) when you should call method `print()` or `printf()`.

Assuming that you can use the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html), you don't need to calculate whether the year is a leap year nor how many days there are in the month you want to display. The date-time API can also give you names of months and names of days of the week and also tell you which day of the week corresponds to a certain date.

Here is a rewrite of your `PrintCalendarV1` class which I renamed to `PrintCalendarV2` and which uses the date-time API. I hope it will be useful to you. Note that rather than ask the user to enter the month and year when the program is running, the below code accepts program arguments. See the comments in the below code for method `main()`.

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Implementation of [UNIX] <tt>cal</tt> command.
 * 
 * @see PrintCalendarV1
 */
public class PrintCalendarV2 {
    private static void printCalendar(int aMonth, int aYear) {
        if (!isValidMonth(aMonth)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month: " + aMonth);
        }
        if (!isValidYear(aYear)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid year: " + aYear);
        }

        // Array index 0 (zero) equals January, hence need to subtract 1 (one) from 'aMonth'.
        Month monthName = Month.values()[aMonth - 1];

        String heading = String.format("%s %d%n", monthName, aYear);
        int len = heading.length();
        int diff = 20 - len;
        int count = diff / 2 + 1;
        String indent = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(count, " "));
        System.out.printf(indent + heading);
        System.out.println("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa");
        int dayOfMonth = 1;
        LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.of(aYear, aMonth, dayOfMonth);
        YearMonth yrMnth = YearMonth.of(aYear, aMonth);
        int monthDays = yrMnth.lengthOfMonth();

        // MONDAY = 1 and SUNDAY = 7, however method 'ordinal()' will return zero for MONDAY.
        int weekDay = theDate.getDayOfWeek().ordinal() + 1;

        if (weekDay == 7) {
            weekDay = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < weekDay; i++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        System.out.printf("%2d", dayOfMonth);
        if (weekDay < 6) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        weekDay++;
        for (; weekDay < 6; weekDay++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", ++dayOfMonth);
        }
        ++dayOfMonth;
        if (weekDay < 7) {
            System.out.printf("%2d", dayOfMonth);
            ++dayOfMonth;
        }
        System.out.println();
        while (dayOfMonth <= monthDays) {
            weekDay = 0;
            for (; weekDay < 6; weekDay++) {
                if (dayOfMonth <= monthDays) {
                    System.out.printf("%2d ", dayOfMonth);
                }
                ++dayOfMonth;
            }
            if (dayOfMonth <= monthDays) {
                System.out.printf("%2d%n", dayOfMonth++);
            }
        }
        if (weekDay < 7) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isValidMonth(int aMonth) {
        return aMonth > 0  &&  aMonth <= 12;
    }

    private static boolean isValidYear(int aYear) {
        return aYear >= Year.MIN_VALUE  &&  aYear <= Year.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    /**
     * Recognizes [<tt>java</tt>] command arguments similar to <tt>cal</tt> command options.
     * <ol>
     * <li>If no arguments, prints current month of current year.</li>
     * <li>If a single argument, it represents a year. Note that 20 represents the year 20 and not
     * the year 2020. Prints the current month in the given year.</li>
     * <li>If two arguments then the first argument is the month of the year where 1 (one) means
     * January, 2 (two) means February, etc. And the second argument is the year. Prints the given
     * month in the given year.</li>
     * </ol>
     * 
     * @param args - <tt>java</tt> command arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int theMonth;
        int theYear;
        YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now();
        if (args.length == 0) {
            theYear = ym.getYear();
            theMonth = ym.getMonthValue();
        }
        else if (args.length == 1) {
            theYear = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            theMonth = ym.getMonthValue();
        }
        else if (args.length > 1) {
            theMonth = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            theYear = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }
        else {
            // args.length is negative?
            theYear = ym.getYear();
            theMonth = ym.getMonthValue();
        }
        if (isValidMonth(theMonth)  &&  isValidYear(theYear)) {
            printCalendar(theMonth, theYear);
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("Invalid month (%d) or year (%d).%n", theMonth, theYear);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is sample output when I run the above code without supplying any arguments.

```
   SEPTEMBER 2020
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. I understood the formatting thing. And the usage of date time API. But I am not allowed to use that,