# Calendar in a nested loop using java

Tags: java, loops, nested

I am a Senior High School student and I'm having a hard time how to add a white spaces in the first row of my calendar using nested loops. We can't use arrays becauce we haven't learned about it yet(it is our next topic).

Our teacher asked us to create a 2020 calendar using nested loops in java. The user need to enter a month using a numerical value (1-12). and we need to display the corresponding calendar for the year 2020 of the entered month.

Here is my code as of now:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter month[1-12]");
int month = s.nextInt();


System.out.println("Sun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThur\tFri\tSat");
    switch(month)
    {
        case 1: //1 stands for the month of January 2020
        for(int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i+ "\t");
            if(i%7 == 0)
            {
            System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the current output of my codes:

```
 Sun   Mon   Tue    Wed   Thu   Fri  Sat
  1     2     3     4      5     6   7                
  8     9    10     11    12    13   14
 15    16    17     18    19    20   21
 22    23    24     25    26    27   28
 29    30    31
```

This the needed sample output on our program in January 2020:

```
   January 2020
   Sun  Mon Tue  Wed  Thu   Fri  Sat
                  1    2    3    4
    5    6   7    8    9    10   11
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
   26   27   28   29   30   31
```

*EDITED*: And this is the sample output on our program in the month of February

```
   February 2020
   Sun  Mon Tue  Wed  Thu   Fri  Sat
                                 1
    2    3   4    5    6    7    8
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
```

Any idea to get there please?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828345/having-issues-with-calendar-printing-based-on-the-input-from-the-user

Comment: No sorry :( because my teacher said no fancy codes. We need our code to be shorter as possible. I hope you understand me hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int sumDay = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the year：");
    int year = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter month：");
    int month = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(year + "year" + month + "month：");
    for (int i = 1900; i < year; i++) {
        if ((i % 4 == 0) && (i % 100 != 0) || (i % 400 == 0)) {
            sumDay += 366;
        } else {
            sumDay += 365;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < month; j++) {
        if (j == 4 || j == 6 || j == 9 || j == 11) {
            sumDay += 30;
        } else if (j == 2) {
            if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
                sumDay += 29;
            } else {
                sumDay += 28;
            }
        } else {
            sumDay += 31;
        }
    }
    /*The above code calculates the total number of days from January 1, 1900 to the entered year and month. If 2020 and 10 are entered, the number of days from 1900.1.1 to 2020.9.30 will be calculated*/

    /*xingQi is used to calculate the day of the week on the 1st of the entered month*/
    int xingQi = (sumDay + 1) % 7;

    int everydayXingQi = sumDay + 1;
    /*monthDay is used to receive the days of the month*/
    int monthDay;
    System.out.println("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");

    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        monthDay = 30;
    } else if (month == 2) {
        if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
            monthDay = 29;
        } else {
            monthDay = 28;
        }
    } else {
        monthDay = 31;
    }

    /*Output the space before the 1st of each month*/
    for (int i = 0; i < xingQi; i++) {
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    /*Output the number of days in each month and control line break*/
    for (int i = 1; i <= monthDay; i++) {
        if (everydayXingQi % 7 == 6) {
            System.out.print(i + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print(i + "\t");
        }
        everydayXingQi++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just changed the year into 2020 because that is our requirement hehe.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some spaces according to days of a month:

```
int year = 2020;
int startDayofYear = 3; // Wednesday is the start day of 2020
int dayCounter = startDayofYear;
int nbrOfDays = 0;
String monthName = "";

for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) { 
    // Switch to chose the month
    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        monthName = "January";
        nbrOfDays = 31;
        break;
    case 2:
        monthName = "February";
        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0) {
            nbrOfDays = 29;
            break;
        } else {
            nbrOfDays = 28;
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        monthName = "March";
        nbrOfDays = 31;
        break;
    case 4:
        monthName = "April";
        nbrOfDays = 30;
        break;
    case 5:
        monthName = "May";
        nbrOfDays = 31;
        break;

    case 6:
        monthName = "June";
        nbrOfDays = 30;
        break;
    case 7:
        monthName = "July";
        nbrOfDays = 31;
        break;
    case 8:
        monthName = "August";
        nbrOfDays = 31;
        break;
    case 9:
        monthName = "September";
        nbrOfDays = 30;
        break;
    case 10:
        monthName = "October";
        nbrOfDays = 31;
        break;
    case 11:
        monthName = "November";
        nbrOfDays = 30;
        break;
    case 12:
        monthName = "December";
        nbrOfDays = 31;
        break;
    }

    System.out.printf("%15s %d  \n", monthName, year);
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n ", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");

    for (int space = 1; space <= startDayofYear; space++) {
        System.out.printf("%4s", "    ");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= nbrOfDays; i++) {
        dayCounter++;
        if (dayCounter % 7 == 0)
            System.out.printf("%- 4d\n", i);
        else
            System.out.printf("%-4d", i);

    }
    startDayofYear = (startDayofYear + nbrOfDays) % 7;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your help and I also understand what you have written there. I have edited the post to show what the output should be. Maybe you could help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, that two sample output must be included in one program only. Sorry for my bad english hehe. I am getting a hard time finishing this task given to us.

Comment: I created a complete code for your problem.

Comment: Sir? I think what you have written there is incorrect? because it is not accurate on our 2020 calendar hehe. Hope you understand

Comment: @James thanks for your comment, I updated the code and it work correctly now.