# 2020 Calendar using nested loops in Java

Tags: java, loops, nested

Our task is to make a 2020 calendar using **nested loops**. The user should input the month in number format [1-12] then **display the calendar for that month**.

Here is my current code

```
public static void main(String ... args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int given;

    do 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter month in number format [1-12]: ");
        given = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
    } while(given > 12 || given <= 0);


    switch(given)
    {
        case 11:
        System.out.println("November 2020");
        System.out.println("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
        for(int y = 1; y <= 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 1; x <=30 ; x++) 
            {
                System.out.print(x + "\t"); 

                if(x % 7 ==0)
                    System.out.println();
            }
        }
        break;
```

The program outputs this:

```
November 2020
   Sun  Mon Tue   Wed Thu   Fri  Sat
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7
   8    9    10   11   12   13   14
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   22   23   24   25   26   27   28
```

How can I do this for the other months in the simplest way possible without using arrays or any fancy code?
For example:

```
January 2020
   Sun  Mon Tue  Wed  Thu   Fri  Sat
                  1    2    3    4
    5    6   7    8    9    10   11
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
   26   27   28   29   30   31
```

Comment: This really is no programming question but a math / logic question. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week . The question basically is: what day of the week is the first of January, first of February, etc. and then offset the data printing based on that information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763790/calendar-in-a-nested-loop-using-java/64763909?noredirect=1#comment114519150_64763909

Comment: If you can't use built-in functionality, then you have two options: either write the code that calculates the first weekday of a given month *or* just have a method that takes first weekday, month name and number of total days as parameters and call it with 12 different sets of values (that you calculated/looked up manually)  in a simple switch method. We can't guess which of those your teacher expects/would accept.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not entirely sure if this would be allowed by your constraints, you could use GregorianCalendar. The bare code would look something like the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Calendar {
    public static main void (String args[]) {
        int year = 2020; 
        int month = 11; 
        showGrid(year, month); 
    }
public static void showGrid(int year, int month) {
    
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, 1); //create a new Gregorian Calendar Object, which allows us to call methods that the GregorianCalendar class has
    int firstDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //get the weekday of the first day of the month
    int currentDay = 0, currentWeekDay = 1; //assign counter variables
    System.out.println("  Sun    Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri    Sat"); //print header
    System.out.println(""); //new line to begin printing days
    
    for(int i = 0; i < firstDay - 1; i++) { //print empty spaces until we get to where the first day should be 
        System.out.print("      |");
    }
    
    for(int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth(month, year);) { //while there are still days left in the month to print
        for(int j = 0; j < 7 && (day <= daysInMonth(month, year)); j++) { //and there are still days left in the specfic week 
            System.out.printf("  %2d  |", day); //print out the day 
            day++; //increment the day counter for the next time we loop through
            currentWeekDay++; //""
            if(7 - (firstDay - 2) == day) { //special case for if we are in the first week (subtracting two from firstDay because zero indexed and we have already incremented above
                break;  
            }
            currentDay = day;  //set the currentDay value, used in below calculations
        }
        if(currentDay <= daysInMonth(month, year)) { //if we have finished printing a week, but there are still days remaining, start printing on a new line 
            emptyLine(); 
            currentWeekDay = 1;
        }
    }
}
}
public static int daysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    if (month == 2) {
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            if(year % 100 == 0) {
                if(year % 400 == 0) {
                    return 29;
                } else {
                    return 28; 
                }
            } else {
                return 29; 
            }
        }
        return 28;
    } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        return 30;
    } else {
        return 31;
    }
}
```

Find [the documentation for the GregorianCalendar Class here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

Essentially:

```
import java.util.*;   
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, 1 //first day);  
int firstDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);   
and then code for edge cases.
```

Comment: We aren't allowed to use those as well. I appreciate your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the first day of the week for each month. You can do that by using [Tomohiko Sakamoto’s Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tomohiko-sakamotos-algorithm-finding-day-week/). Then you format the spacing accordingly for each month.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calendar {
    // function to implement tomohiko sakamoto algorithm
    public static int day_of_the_week(int y, int m, int d)
    {
        // array with leading number of days values
        int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 };
    // if month is less than 3 reduce year by 1
    if (m < 3)
        y -= 1;

    return (y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + t[m - 1] + d) % 7;
}

public static void checkMonth(String month, int days, int shiftDays){
    String spaces = "";
    switch (shiftDays){
        case 1:
            spaces = "\t";
            break;
        case 2:
            spaces = "\t\t";
            break;
        case 3:
            spaces = "\t\t\t";
            break;
        case 4:
            spaces = "\t\t\t\t";
            break;
        case 5:
            spaces = "\t\t\t\t\t";
            break;
        case 6:
            spaces = "\t\t\t\t\t\t";
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(month + " 2020");
    System.out.println("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
    int shift = 7-shiftDays;
        for (int x = 1; x <= days; x++) {
            // prints the first row of dates with respective spaces
            if (x <= 1) {
                System.out.print(spaces + x + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print(x + "\t");
            }

            if (x % shift == 0) {
                System.out.println();
                shift = shift + 7;
            }
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int given;
    int year = 2020;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter month in number format [1-12]: ");
        given = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
    } while (given > 12 || given <= 0);


String month = "";
int days = 0;
int shiftDays = day_of_the_week(year, given, 1);
    switch (given) {
        case 1:
            month = "January";
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            month = "February";
            /*if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100!= 0)) || (year%400 == 0)) {
                days = 29;
                }
            else
                days = 28;
                */
            //Since the year is 2020 is a leap year we can hardcode the value
            days = 29;
            break;
        case 3:
            month = "March";
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
            month = "April";
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 5:
            month = "May";
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 6:
            month = "June";
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 7:
            month = "July";
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 8:
            month = "August";
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 9:
            month = "September";
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 10:
            month = "October";
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 11:
            month = "November";
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 12:
            month = "December";
            days = 31;
            break;
    }
    checkMonth(month,days,shiftDays);
}

}
```

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your help. Sadly we haven't lectured about arrays yet so I don't think I can use those. Is there any way to remove the array? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You can specify the shift in days for each month, since you have only the year 2020. You can hardcode it.
 `int shiftDays = 0;
        
switch (given) {
            
case 1:
                month = "January";
                days = 31;
                shiftDays = 3;
                break;` 
So you specify it for each month. By doing this you can delete the Tomohiko Sakamoto Algorithm.